# The kids all or All the kids

Tags: word-order, quantifiers

Which of the sentences below is correct? Please explain why.

> 1. **The kids all** go to school on the same bus
> 2. **All the kids** go to school on the same bus

Answer (score 1):

Both forms of the sentence are in general use and grammatically correct, except for the lack of full stops.

1. is a more formal, less emotional way of communicating.
2. communicates a greater emotionality about the situation and is generally more casual/less formal.

Comment: As you say, they'e both fine. But I can't find the *emotional* nuance that you refer to.